# Continuity at a point in metric spaces doesn't imply topological continuity?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

We proved in a lecture that the metric continuity at a point is equivalent to the topological continuity at that point:

> A function $f\colon (X_1, d_1)\to (X_2, d_2)$ is continuous at $x\in X_1$ iff for every open ball $B$ centered around $f(x)$, there exists an open ball around $x$ that is mapped inside $B$ via $f$.

> A function $f\colon (X_1, \tau_1)\to (X_2, \tau_2)$ is continuous at $x\in X_1$ iff for every open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, we have that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

But then, consider $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ (both under the standard metric topology, so that the above result applies) given by
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
x, & x\ne -1\\
1, & x = -1
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $f$ is clearly metric continuous at $1$. But it's not topological continuous at $1$ since $(0, 2)$ is an open neighborhood of $f(1)$ and $f^{-1}((0, 2)) = (0, 2)\cup\{-1\}$ which is not open.

What is wrong with this "counterexample"?

---

It turns out that my definition for topological continuity is not quite "correct". The correct one is the one that Zerox proposed in the comments: $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff for every (open) neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood (*not necessarily open*) of $x$. This implies that for every open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.

The confusion crept in since I though that the above implies my definition for topological continuity, which is not the case. My "proof" went like this:

Let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $f(x)$. To show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open, let $y\in f^{-1}(V)$, *i.e.*, $f(y)\in V$. Since $V$ is an open neighborhood for $f(y)$ too, we can choose an open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$. Then $U\subseteq f^{-1}(f(U))\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.

Then Zerox pointed out the flaw in my "proof" and everything fits perfectly now.

Comment: The topological definition of "continuity at a point" you proposed is wrong. It only requires "For every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x$", no need to satisfy that $f^{-1}(V)$ is *open*. And you can easily prove this weaker definition is the correct one equivalent to the metric continuity.

Comment: @Zerox what do you mean? What's your definition of neighborhood then?

Comment: A set $V$ is called a neighborhood of $x \in V$ iff $V$ contains an open set $U$ that contains $x$.

Comment: I believe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762135/equivalence-of-continuity-between-metric-and-topological-spaces may answer your question.

Comment: @Zerox I see; for me (following Munkres) a neighborhood $x\in U$ is an open set containing $x$.

Comment: Then the two definitions of "continuity at a point" you proposed are **not equivalent**. You can never deduce from the metric definition that $f^{-1}(B)$ is open if we **only** have the continuity at $x$.

Comment: Where did you get the second definition from?

Comment: @Zerox I think your definition implies mine, as I have proven in the "answer" below. But then, I might have made some error in the proof.

Comment: You get wrong in the proof. $f$ is **not** supposed to be continuous at $y$, so the neighborhood $U \ni y$ that is mapped into $V \ni f(y)$ may not exist. Remember in the definition **only when $x$ is a continuous point could we find a neighborhood of $x$ mapped into a selected neighborhood of $f(x)$**.

Comment: It is a bit more esthetically pleasing to define continuity at a point by: $f: X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Here a *neighborhood* is understood in the sense of Bourbaki.

Comment: IMO, rather than switching definition of neighborhood. I think, following is the conventional way to define continuity at a point in topological sense: $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ iff $\forall V\in \mathcal{N}_{f(x)}$, $\exists U\in \mathcal{N}_x$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4352659/861687) is more equivalent definition of continuity. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4358173/861687) is proof of equivalent definition of continuity in metric space and topological sense.

Answer (score 3):

A definition that avoids the use of the word "neighborhood" (so avoids a collision Munkres/Bourbaki).

$f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for every open set $U$ with $f(x)\in U$  an open set $V$ exists with $x\in V$ and $f(V)\subseteq U$.

Of course here you can replace $f(V)\subseteq U$ by the equivalent statement: $V\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$.

For $x=1$ and $U=(0,2)$ in your example e.g. $V=(0,2)$ does the job, and of course there are more choices for $V$.

Answer (score 0):

The function f IS NOT CONTINUOUS everywhere. It is continuous on (0,2) and then you get $f^{-1}$(0,2)=(0,2) which is open! If you are interested in one point x=1 then the definition is :Let f be a function defined from topological space X to topological space Y, then f is said to be continuous at a point x∈X if for every neighborhood V of f(x), there exists a neighborhood U of x, such that f(U)⊆V ! It says THERE EXISTS it does not say for all neighborhoods of a. So 1 is certainly a continuity point because if V=(0,2) THERE EXISTS a U=(1-ε,1+ε) such that f(U)$\subseteq $ V=(0,2). I cant make it clearer!